# Add item inside BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I need to add item inside BehaviorSubject.

I need add item with name in every object ( item name expanded )
What i try:

Comment: it's unclear for me : what's the type of `response` and the type of `dates`?

Comment: I will try to explain better wait minute

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
this.someService.getList()
  .subscribe(dates => {
    const fixedDates = dates.map(el => ({...el, expanded: false}));
    this.dates.next(fixedDates)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to add **expanded** property in BehaviorSubject's value array.

This is how you do it, BehaviorSubject has `value` property that contains the last emitted data.

```
this.dates.value.forEach(val => (val.expanded = true));
console.log(this.dates.value);
```

Note: Modify data first then emit the next value (As shown by @Bojan Kogoj), or else existing subscribers will not get the latest modified data.

Answer (score 0):

This is how usually I do it in my service:

```
private refresh$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

read$(): Observable<Order[]>{
    return this.refresh$.pipe(switchMap(()=>
            this.http.get<Order[]>(`${this._url}/orders`)));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the 'expanded' property to every object inside the array, do something like this:

```
private datesSource: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.test);
public datesObservable$: Observable<any> = this.datesSource.asObservable();

this.datesSource.next(response); // Set your dates object and subscribe to the observale

this.datesObservable$.subscribe(datesObsdata => {
  datesObsdata.forEach(eachObj => {
    if (eachObj && !eachObj['expanded']) {
      eachObj['expanded'] = false;
    }
  })
})
```